# Weird img shifting when using jQuery slideDown and slideUp

Tags: jquery, html

I've the following html structure:

```
<div class ='profileName'>
   <hr>
   <span class='name'>Content</span>
</div>
<div class ='profile'>
<div class='floatRightImg padded'>
<img src='imgUrl' class='shadow'/>
    </div>
    <p>description</p>
</div>
```

with the following CSS linked:

```
hr {
color: #CCCCCC;
}

.floatRightImg {
float: right;
}

.profile {
height: 450px;
width: 700px;
margin: auto;
}

.profileName {
width: 700px;
margin: auto;
}

.shadow {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.padded {
padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
}

.name {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #CCCCCC;
left: 70px;
padding: 0 8px;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.name:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

and I'm using the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".name").click(function(){
                var toBeSlided = $(this).parent("div").next("div");
                if(toBeSlided.is(":visible")) {
                    toBeSlided.slideUp();
                } else {
                    toBeSlided.slideDown();
                }
            });

        });
```

Everything is working as I want (sliding down-showing- and up-hiding- the content of the 'profile' div when I click on the 'name' span. The problem is that I noticed a weird effect: the floating image perform a weird shifting up when I close the div and down when I open the div. In other words, it doesn't remain fixed while showing or hiding the content (as a matter of fact, it is part of the content to be hided/showed). Any possible explanation to that behavior?
Thanks to everybody in advance.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k2wv/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your p element next to your float right.
http://jsfiddle.net/6k2wv/3/

```
<div class ='profileName'>
   <hr>
   <span class='name'>Content</span>
</div>
<div class ='profile'>
    <div class='floatRightImg padded'>
        <img src='http://www.polpenuil.it/convenzioni/images/smile.jpg' class='shadow'/>
    </div>
    <p style="float: left;">description</p>
</div>
```

Note the new float left.

Also, you can simplify your JS code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name").click(function(){
        var toBeSlided = $(this).parent("div").next("div");
        toBeSlided.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

It's generally best practice to avoid stringing .parent/.next calls. You end up with confusing code that depends on specific DOM structure. Instead, give the element a unique class and select that directly outside of your event.

```
$(function(){
    var smileyFace = $(".smiley-face");
    $(".name").click(function(){
        smileyFace.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! However i don't want to float left the text cause i want it wrapped around the image. I solved that way:
    <p>
       <img src='blabla' align='right'>
       description
    </p>

Furthermore i can't either avoid chaining parent/next calls because i've not a single element that i can provide with a unique id but a list of dynamically generated elements, each one with its own sliding control